# Signals and Systems - Alternate notation for systems of signals?

Tags: notation

I specifically have a problem with certain notation used to describe systems of signals (context: Signals and Systems by Oppenheim, et. al.); from the Center for Computer Research in Music and Acoustics (Stanford University):

[image]

[image: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/img467.png]

The current material I am learning with likes to use something similar along these lines. Particularly, in proofs, I have a hard time differentiating between the system proper and the inputs to the system, as the system is not allocated a specific variable to represent it before evaluation/substitution/abstraction or "binding."

Can I represent a system with a more function-like notation: e.g.:

$$H[f(x)] = f(2x)$$

To me, this seems a lot clearer, but it seems to break down in the context of ordinary differential equations:

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + (sin\ t)(y(t)) = 3x(t)$$

Would the following be a good notation for the above?

$$H[y(t), x(t)] = \{ \frac{dy(t)}{dt} + (sin\ t)(y(t)) = 3x(t) \}$$

Or, am I misunderstanding something that is causing me to "not get" the notation?

I am looking for a clear notation that expresses the signals and their dependencies clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly mean.

In general, $x[n]$ represents the **input** of the system, and y[n] the **output**. (Except for the specific illustration)

We always use $H(\cdot)$ to represent a filter. ( But you can use it to represent a general transform , just the notation)

If you define the function $H(\cdot)$ with the first argument $x[n]$ and the second one $y[n]$, then it seems no problem.

An advise: if you want to ask the questions about Signal Processing, please post question on this [page](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: Is there a difference between a filter/transform and a system? I once asked whether the Fourier transform is a system, but I couldn't understand the answer...

Comment: @VermillionAzure  The difference bewteen the output and input is the transform( system transfers $x[n]$ to $y[n]$) . Filter is one of the transforms

Comment: Can you restate that? It's not clear to me what you're trying to say.

Comment: Fourier Transform is **not** a system.  It does not transfers the $x[n]$ to other things. It is a mathematical tool to calculate the spectrum, which is another angle to look at the signal

Comment: @VermillionAzure I am very sorry that I misunderstand the 'transfer'.( not native speaker) . Transform means changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in practice a linear systems is not "naturally" given by an explicit function $H(x) = y$ that maps an input signal $x$ to an output signal $y$, but rather an implicit relation like your example:
$$
y'(t) + \sin t \, y(t) = 3 x(t), \quad y(0) = y_0 \quad (1)
$$
Provided this equation has a unique solution, this equation represents a linear system $H$ that maps an input signal $x$ to an output $y$, but we have no explicit formula for $H$ in this case.

To answer your question, I think the best notation is to stick with (1), and simply state which signal is the input and which signal is the output if you need to be extra clear.

Comment: One problem I have with the notation is that having to specify what the input/output signal per "instantiation" or specialization of the general equation to specific signals (e.g. x1 into x and y1 into y) is that we lose the information that specialization of the general equation is derived from that same system. Also, isn't H in this case simply the entirely of (1) minus the initial condition definition? Or does this cause a problem with substitution?